# No value for 'distinct' has been declared in Mongoose 3.8.31

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, distinct

I'm trying to use 'distinct' Mongoose operation but it's not working properly. I'm using Mongoose 3.8.31 because I need this specific version to use a particular mongoose driver.

The code I'm using responds with the error **No value for 'distinct' has been declared**.

Here is my code:

```
var query = {};

Channel.distinct(query, 'name', function (err, channels) { 
     if (err) {
          res.send(err);
     } else {
          res.send(channels);
     }
});
```

I'm following the distinct operation format of Mongoose 3.8.31, like link below

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [distinct signature](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct) you are using applies to the Mongoose [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#query-js) i.e. you need to chain the **[`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct)** method to a query:

```
Channel.find().distinct('name', function (err, channels) { 
     if (err) {
          res.send(err);
     } else {
          res.send(channels);
     }
});
```

---

You can also apply the **[`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct)** method straight on the model as follows:

```
var query = {};
Channel.distinct('name', query, function (err, channels) { 
     if (err) {
          res.send(err);
     } else {
          res.send(channels);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried with the two options but I get this error: "**TypeError: this.collection.distinct is not a function**"

Comment: Is `Channel` a Mongoose model?